# Jenkinsfile - Mutual exclusivity across multiple pipelines

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking for a way to make multiple declaratively written Jenkinsfiles only run exclusively and block each other. They consume test instances who will be terminated after they run which causes problems when PRs are being tested as they come in.

- I cannot find an option to make [the BuildBlocker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) do this, all the jenkinsfiles that use this plugin are not running in our Plugin/Jenkins version schema and it seems as if these `[$class: <some.java.expression>]` strings being exported from the syntax generator don't work here anyways.
- I cannot find a way to run these [Locks](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) over all the steps involved in the pipeline.
- I could hack a file-lock but this won't help me with multi-node builds.

Answer (score 2):

This plugin could perhaps help you as it allows to lock resources you've declared previously so that if a resource is currently locked, any other job that requires the same resource will wait until it is released.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/

Comment: Sorry for late response, my family got sick. I'll give you the bounty, if you can provide me with a minimal example for 2 mutual exclusive jenkins pipelines.

Comment: Not sure it is what your looking for, the lock is applied inside  steps of the pipeline.
You need to create a lock label in system configuration once the plugin is installed. Then you can run two pipelines like this one, the first started will lock the resources and the second one will start but the step will wait for the lock to be released.
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('Example') {        
        steps {
          lock('myLock') {
           echo 'Getting lock'
            sleep 100
            echo 'Release lock now'
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

Comment: > pipeline { agent any stages { stage('Example') { steps { lock('myLock') { echo 'Getting lock' sleep 100 echo 'Release lock now' } } } } }

As I understand it, this does not lock the whole pipeline and there is no way to do that? So a pipeline would always start and then wait until the lock is free?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want declarative, probably wait for the currently-in-review [Allow locking multiple stages in declarative pipeline](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43336) jira issue to be completed. You can also vote for it and watch it.

And if you can't wait, this is your opportunity to learn golang (or whatever language you want to learn) by implementing a microservice that holds these locks that you call from your pipeline scripts. :D

Answer (score 0):

The JobDSL plugin is for configuring Jenkins execution policies including blocking another and calling pipeline code.
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.blockOn describes the method, which also the blocker plugin uses.

This is the tutorial for usage https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL, the api https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands.

Taken from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-jenkins-job-configuration-using-job-dsl:

It should be possible to use https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL, but I found no good usage example yet.